# Trigger native lead convert after screen flow

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

We have a fairly common scenario.  Some fields on lead are not required as its unrealistic that all leads will have this info at creation.

BUT they are required on Acct/contact/op hence are needed to be populated prior to lead conversion.

The current process is clunky if you go to convert and have forgotten one of these fields you have to go back to the lead and populate it then convert again, the convert process only throws one error at a time so you might have to repeat that process multiple times.

What I would like to implement is a custom button that launches a screen flow if any of the conversion required fields are empty. The screen flow just has the convert required fields on it.  Once a user has completed these the screen flow just redirects to the native lead convert page which wont fail as all fields have been populated.

Any ideas how on completion of a screen flow you can launch the native lead convert function?  I know you can redirect after a flow but the convert screen is a pop up not a stand alone page.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to standard lead convert page in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302605/how-to-redirect-to-standard-lead-convert-page-in-lightning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the url:

https://YOUR_SF_DOMAIN.com/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole?leadConvert__leadId={*LEAD ID*}

Credit this post - [How to redirect to standard lead convert page in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302605/how-to-redirect-to-standard-lead-convert-page-in-lightning)